# Top corners curved in IE on current page link

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Can someone help me understand a way of adding rounded corners top left and top right of the current page link below?  I have used jQuery corners but this doesnt work in IE very well... I was looking to use PNG.  The space between the corners should be white.  The PNG would be transparent letting whatever image was below to show through.

```
<ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Create Account</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Order a Catalogue</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Distributors</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Login</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the `<ul>` have a fixed width?  This is a pertinent detail.

Comment: yes it does Josh! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Draw your rounded rectangle in something like [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) (make sure you have a transparent background!) and make it the exact width of the `LI`.  Give it more than enough height so that you can cut off the button rounded corners and it will still be tall enough to fill the `LI`.  Cut off the bottom rounded corners, crop accordingly, and save it as a PNG.  Set it as a background image on the element with CSS...

```
ul li.current {
  background:url(../images/nav-current.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Note: if you use a background color on the `LI`, it will bleed through the transparent part of the rounded corners, which is not good.

**Moving forward**... you can just use the CSS3 `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` along with `background-color` (no images!), but these are not supported in IE8 and older.

Comment: I forgot to mention the menu items need to expand

Comment: @Andy If I am understanding what you mean by "expand", you can just make the image tall enough and that will be no problem.  Background images can be bigger than their container and it will not cause an overflow.

Comment: Its the width im thinking about, if its not a set width you can't use a fixed image.

Comment: @Andy You said the list has a fixed width.

Comment: Sorry i meant the UL was a fixed, with varying li.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Hey friend to apply border radius that works in IE also you have to apply border-radius.htc file and you can apply it to your CSS like this one. In my project i am using it on Div tag but you can use it whereever you want.

```
div
{
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
background: #D4D0C8;
border: 1px solid #808080;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
}
```

you will find border-radius.htc file on google also. If you can provide your emailid then i can mail it to you if you want

Comment: Is the border-radius path relative to the css file or html file?

Comment: Andy, Yes i have tested it in IE, Chrome and Firefox it works very well. border-radius file is related to CSS file.